# Package Install custom validation error - can't use template with page type AppPage

Tags: lightning-apps, validation, package, custom, install

Need help resolving a package install validation error.

I'm installing a managed package (containing a newly developed custom app) into a test org for the first time. I get two of the following validation errors (one for each template of type AppPage):

> This app can't be installed 
>   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "You can't use template XXX:XXX_HomeTemplate with page type AppPage.".

Notes:

- The App references  two tab/flexipage/pageTemplate triplets.
- The flexipage is of type AppPage.

Following are code snippets:

### .app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#0070D2</headerColor>
        <logo>XXXXX_Logo</logo>
        <logoVersion>1</logoVersion>
    </brand>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <label>XXXXX</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <tab>XXXXX_Pipeline1</tab>
    <tab>XXXXX_BaseReport</tab>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    <utilityBar>XXXXX_alpha1_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
</CustomApplication>
```

### .tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Created by Lightning App Builder</description>
    <flexiPage>XXXHome</flexiPage>
    <label>XXX Pipeline</label>
    <mobileReady>true</mobileReady>
    <motif>Custom17: Sack</motif>
</CustomTab>
```

### .flexipage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>XXXXXXX</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>graphPane</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>XXXXXXX</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>tablePane</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>XXXXXXX</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>performancePane</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>XXXXXXX/componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>logPane</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>XXXXXXX</masterLabel>
    <pageTemplate>XXX _HomeTemplate</pageTemplate>
    <type>AppPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

### XXX_HomeTemplate.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:appHomeTemplate" access="global"
    description="XXXXXXXXXX">
...
</aura:component>
```

Comment: For a similar issue in past, removing UtilityBar from app had worked.

Comment: Thx, I tried removing the utilityBar but this yielded the same result--validation error.

Comment: I've isolated the problem to the use of custom pageTemplates. When i use one of the standard pageTemplates (Header and Three Regions) I don't get the validation error and make it through the install successfully. 

I still need to understand why my custom pageTemplate has issues.

Comment: Do you have My Domain enabled, seen package install problems specifically with page templates if it is not